# Tinycme editor in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I want to add a lightweight grid plugin for Tinymce in Ruby on Rails so that I can achieve Column Formatting like Microsoft Word. The above plugin is for WordPress. How can I achieve it in Rails as I am using tinymce-rails gem.